# Matrix notation for entropy

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors, information-theory, entropy

If entropy is

$$H(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} p(x_i) \ln\bigg(\frac{1}{p(x_i)}\bigg)$$

how can this be written in matrix notation found in linear algebra, which replaces product summations with bold-faced vectors, i.e. $\mathbf{p}$?

Also not sure how the natural log of a vector (here, vector of inverse probabilities) can be written as a bold vector. would that part just be $\ln(\mathbf{p}^{-1})$?

Comment: This is a notation-based question. If you specify somewhere that by writing $\ln \mathbf p$ you mean the vector $(\ln p_1,\ldots,\ln p_N)$, then of course, you can say that $H(X) = -\mathbf p \cdot \ln \mathbf p$.

Comment: aren't u missing the vector of ones that does the summation?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: if we weren't talking about entropy and just how to sum the elements of one vector $\mathbf{x}$ we would be required to introduce a ones vector $\mathbf{1}$ to do the summation of its elements by multiplying $\mathbf{x}$ by it. but i guess in this case, the ln(p) is basically that one vector multiplied by what we need so it's already implicit in this case

Comment: Again, that's a question of notation. Specify that $\mathbf 1 = (1,\ldots,1)$ and then you are free to write $\sum_i \ln p_i = \mathbf 1 \cdot \ln \mathbf p$.

Comment: is it correct notation to use $\mathbf{p}^{-1}$ as being equal to the original $\mathbf{p}$ vector except that all of its elements are inverted?

Comment: You are free to use your own notation as long as a) the notation is clearly explained to the reader; b) you remain consistent with this notation. In the particular case of $\mathbf p ^{-1}$, why not?